# Flask: Getting at Blueprint options in view code

Tags: python, flask

Flask's blueprints let me pass optional values when I register a blueprint.
But how do I get them later?

```
from flask import Blueprint, g

bp = Blueprint('test', __name__, url_prefix='/test')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    ... now where do I get the value of `foo` from? ...

app.register_blueprint(bp, foo="bar")
```

Comment: do you mean "register_blueprint" instead of "register"? there is no "register" method on Flask application objects

Comment: of course. Corrected.

Comment: as to why I need that: the view is in a blueprint generated by flask_admin, otherwise I'd just subclass it or pass a parameter to _init__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the options that you pass in to `register_blueprint` are only used for Flask's internal setup of the blueprint (e.g. configuring the url_prefix, subdomain, etc. options). They aren't available at request time.

Maybe it would be helpful if you explain why you want to access that value from within the request?

Have you considered using a pluggable view?

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/

With views you can subclass `View`, then override `__init__` to pass values in which are usable from within the request.

You can also subclass Blueprint and do the same thing, it's just a little more code & complexity. I did something like that [here](https://bitbucket.org/lost_theory/flask-stripe-blueprint/src/default/itemshop/__init__.py#cl-13) (see BlueprintWrapper). Although if I were to rewrite it I would try to get rid of the metaclass.

Comment: Seems like provided example of BlueprintWrapper is not accessible anymore

Answer (score 1):

The options that you pass to `register_blueprint` end up being passed to `werkzeug.routing.Rule`, and don't seem to be stored anywhere in between.

As we can see from the [constructor of Rule](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L421), all irrelevant parameters that you supply are dropped.

```
class Rule(RuleFactory):
    def __init__(self, string, defaults=None, subdomain=None, methods=None,
                 build_only=False, endpoint=None, strict_slashes=None,
                 redirect_to=None, alias=False, host=None)
```

This means that you probably won't succeed in accessing `foo` unless you create a subclass of Blueprint that stores it for you.